# Composer lock files in vendor dir

Tags: composer-php

I've just come across the https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/security-advisories tool which looks a great way to automatically scan for the vulnerabilities that are in that community-contributed database.

It scans a `composer.lock` file for packages with vulnerabilities. However, it's made me realise that my understanding of Composer is not what it should be!

I have a project that has a `composer.json` file that `require`s a single `demo/package`. That demo package also has requirements, like `demo/dep`.

The result of running `composer install --no-dev` is that I have a `composer.lock` file which includes:

- `demo/package` version `1.0`
- `demo/dep` version `1.2`

All good so far, and running `symfony security:check /path/to/my/project/composer.lock` gives me a green light, no vulnerabilities.

However on close inspection of the files now in my `vendor` dir, I can see there's a `vendor/demo/package/composer.lock` file, which contains references to `demo/dep` at version `1.1` - which has a security vulnerability against it.

As I understand, I have the safer `1.2` version installed - so says *my* project's `composer.lock` file, but **why is a `composer.lock` file included with the vendor's package**?

Does that mean that the dodgy code is installed somewhere, too? Or can I just simply ignore the `composer.lock` files if there's a `composer.lock` file in a dir above it or such? `composer show` does not list the versions in the nested lock file. Or maybe I should ignore composer.lock files if there's no sibling `./vendor/` dir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply inspect your folders to find a vulnerable version? If there was any, you should find a `vendor` folder within that package, that's where that package could have installed stuff from it's own `composer.lock`

Usually, only the `composer.json` of a package is evaluated to install dependencies. If there is a lock file within one package's folder, you should ask the maintainer of that package **why** this is the case, but for installing dependencies on your system, this does not matter.

Side note: writing "usually" refers to the standard model of installations. I've seen some crude stuff where Composer plugins put other rules in place, but this cannot be said for your project without knowing more about the structure.